# How to make full body with PhysicsFactory.createTriangulatedBody() and EarClippingTriangulator in andEngine/Android

Tags: android, box2d, andengine, game-physics, sensors

I am making simple game - kind of race game, where you see from the "sky" your sprites with Box2D bodies attached and they have to move along some path. My idea was to detect if they will go out of the path by detecting their contact with invisible body (**set as sensor**) covering the path. My code looks like that:

```
ArrayList<Vector2> UniqueBodyVertices = new ArrayList<Vector2>();
    UniqueBodyVertices.addAll((List<Vector2>) ListUtils.toList(new Vector2[] {               
             new Vector2(-432, -95),
             new Vector2(-326, -22),
             new Vector2(-327, 17), 
             new Vector2(-440, 96),
             new Vector2(-444, 238),
             new Vector2(-393, 290),
             ...
             new Vector2(-303, -279), 
             new Vector2(-425, -285) 

     }));


    List<Vector2> UniqueBodyVerticesTriangulated = new EarClippingTriangulator().computeTriangles(UniqueBodyVertices);


    float[] meshTriangles = new float[UniqueBodyVerticesTriangulated.size() * 3];
    for(int i = 0; i < UniqueBodyVerticesTriangulated.size(); i++){
        meshTriangles[i*3] = UniqueBodyVerticesTriangulated.get(i).x;
        meshTriangles[i*3+1] = UniqueBodyVerticesTriangulated.get(i).y;

        UniqueBodyVerticesTriangulated.get(i).mul(1/PhysicsConstants.PIXEL_TO_METER_RATIO_DEFAULT);
    }




    Sprite bg = new Sprite(0, 0, 1024, 768, ResourceManager.getInstance().mBackGroundRegion, getVertexBufferObjectManager());

    Mesh mesh = new Mesh(0, 0, meshTriangles, UniqueBodyVerticesTriangulated.size(), DrawMode.LINE_STRIP , getVertexBufferObjectManager());

    mesh.setColor(Color.RED);


    Body meshBody = PhysicsFactory.createTrianglulatedBody(physicsWorld, mesh, UniqueBodyVerticesTriangulated, BodyType.StaticBody, PhysicsFactory.createFixtureDef(0f, 0f, 0f, true));
    physicsWorld.registerPhysicsConnector(new PhysicsConnector(mesh, meshBody, true, true));
    meshBody.setUserData("trasa");
```

I deleted some of the vertices just to shorten the code here. I also know that there should be `BodyType.Triangles` and not `BodyType.LineStrip` - it is just for checking bodies behaviour and does not change anything. Anyway what I pasted here works, and my path is covered with body like I want to, but the problem is detecting the contact. I have another part of code for `ContactListener`:

```
@Override
        public void endContact(Contact contact) {
            final Fixture x1 = contact.getFixtureA();
            final Fixture x2 = contact.getFixtureB();
            if(x2.getBody().getUserData().equals("kapselBialy")&&x1.getBody().getUserData().equals("trasa"))
            {
                mScene.setBackground(new Background(Color.RED));

            }

            if(x2.getBody().getUserData().equals("trasa")&&x1.getBody().getUserData().equals("kapselBialy"))
            {
                mScene.setBackground(new Background(Color.RED));

            }

        }
```

The problem is that inside my body there are a lot of triangles and some of them are the parts of my path body and some or not. From outside the whole path is treated as one body. But when my players body is hovering on it (full contact) it is sometimes detected as in contact and sometimes not. It looks like some of triangles are treated as a body and some are not. The question is how to make it so the whole path is treated as one body without holes?

**EDIT**
I attach image from the project.As you can see there are triangles created by the triangulation. My sprite detects some of them as a body of the path, and some not (I check this by `endContact()`). So how can I do that so all of the triangles are treateed as one body? Just to add: If I make the path body not sensor, and try to bounce my sprite from outside it works: the path body is solid from outside on whole length, but not inside of the path body. Hope it is more clear now.

[image]

Comment: This question could use a picture or two to explain what you mean - I don't understand how some triangles could be parts of the path and some not. As a suggestion, how about using chain or edge shapes for the boundary of the path, and check when the player crosses those lines. You would need to make sure the player starts inside the path, and not touching any of the lines.

Comment: @iforce2d - Hi, of courrse I had the idea to just put lines around my path but, what if my sprite just touches the line and then goes back to the path? It should not work like that. The best would be to check if it touches the path, but now I have a problem with this triangles.

Comment: I see. How about using a raycast between the previous position and the current position, and check if it hits a path edge fixture.

Comment: Thanks for idea. I found your tutorial and will look into that. Never knew about that possibility, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED! Ok so the idea to check if our player body left the body of our path is to count borders playerbody passes. So in contactlistener we make beginContact to add one to some int variable (lets say bordersPassed) and endContact subtracts one from it. So when our player is inside path this variable will always be bigger than 0. When it leaves path it will be 0. And thats what we check.